# Add class with old data in a form

Tags: laravel

I try to add class on a label if an the input has old datas.

I try this on my label:

```
<?php empty(old(email)) ? '' : 'active' ;?>
```

But it doesn't work. I also try with "isset" but I have an error exception.

Can you help me ? Thank you

Comment: Can you add the error exception you are getting?

Comment: Just email is not defined

Comment: did you try `is_null(email)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old method takes the input name as a string. You can also use blade syntax to make things easier.

```
<label class="label{{ old('email') ? ' active' : '' }}" >Test</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `old` function accepts string as its first parameter. You're likely getting the error because constant `email` does not exists. Instead, call it with string `old('email')`

```
<?php empty(old('email')) ? '' : 'active' ;?>
```